# How to set VS 2008 version option for TFS 2017 build definition

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2008

I am new to TFS and am trying to build an VB project created with Visual Studio 2008 using Team Foundation Server 2017 Build feature.

As you can see on the image below, I need to set the Visual Studio version on the Build Solution task and there is no dropdown option for Visual Studio 2008.

Is there anyway I can select VS 2008 to build this project?
Or is it possible to do this?

I will appreciate of any help I can get.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided from Microsoft at [TFS Server Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/requirements), and specifically looking into the Client Compatibility / Visual Studio 2008 falls under the MSSCCI support category:

> MSSCCI support
>   Visual Studio/Team Explorer 2008 and Visual Studio 2005 are no longer officially supported. To connect to the server, these clients must interface through the MSSCCI provider instead. MSSCCI support only includes support for source control integration and MSSCCI commands. The goal is simply to allow developers to continue working with legacy applications in an upgraded server.

I believe that, if you have to stick with Visual Studio 2008, you could use MSBuild step instead, and specify the proper location of the MSBuild 3.5, and verify if this would work for you:
[image]

Comment: Thank you Danko! I will try to use MSBuild task instead of Build Solution task then. I tell my teammate to try it and let you know how it goes.